# Twitter Widget Doesnt Show in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, twitter, widget, twitter-widget

I created a twitter widget to append in my library management system, but it doesn't work. The preview of twitter widget seems to be blank, it doesn't show .

[image]

When I tried to paste the code into the HTML of my site , it doesn't change everything. I tried accessing twitter in Firefox and everything seems to work right. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Try disabling your adblocker and refresh.